# How to find roots of $f(z)=(a+yg(z))^2+g(z)^2=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, numerical-methods, roots

I want to find the roots of 
$$f(z)=\left[a+zg(z)\right]^2+g(z)^2=0$$

Where $a$ is real number and:
$$
g(z)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{z^2+1}}\ln\left(\frac{z+\sqrt{z^2+1}}{z-\sqrt{z^2+1}}\right)
$$

**It said that $f(z)=0$ has double complex roots when $a\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, no complex root when $a>\pi/2$ and four complex roots when $a<-\pi/2$.**

**It also said that the complex roots are pure imaginary, and come in conjugate pairs.** The paper is published in a well known journal, [here is the link](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.96.230403), see page 3.

What I tried is that expand f(z) around $z=0$, I get:
$$
f(z)=(a^2-\frac{\pi^2}{4}) +i\pi(a+1)z +(1+2a)z^2+O(z^3)
$$

The constant term is $a^2-\pi^2/4$, does this constant term give the above claim? I don't know.

**My question is: 1). how to determine the number of complex roots for different value of $a$? 2).If possible, can you express the roots as a function of $a$? 3).If it is very hard to express analytically, could you give a hint how can I find all of them numerically?**

Comment: i would recommend to rewrite everything in terms of $z=\sinh[q]$
This will give you a much simpler $g[z]$!

Comment: @tired a very good recommendation indeed.

Comment: There is probably a small error here: there should be four roots for $a < -\frac \pi 2$ (note the "minus" sign). Also, shouldn't you study the cases $a = \pm \frac \pi 2$?

Comment: @AlexM. You are right, the typo is fixed. This problem is abstracted from a practical problem, the limiting cases are not interested. However, on the mathematical side, this two cases should be considered.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? Are you interested in finding the roots, or in studying their number as a function of $a$?

Comment: @AlexM. I think both, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not hard, albeit numerically, to show all the features stated in this question. Because the roots come in pairs of pure imaginary numbers, I guess it is doable to show the features analytically as well.
The very first step is to derive
$$
a=\frac{\pm\mathrm{i}-z}{2\sqrt{z^2+1}}\ln\left(\frac{z+\sqrt{z^2+1}}{z-\sqrt{z^2+1}}\right).
$$
Then, here goes the plots (bird's eye-view & side view) of the real part of RHS (when the imaginary part is sufficiently small) for both $+\mathrm{i}$ and $-\mathrm{i}$. They are symmetric w.r.t. $x$-axis and $+\mathrm{i}$ and $-\mathrm{i}$ plots are reflections w.r.t. $y$-axis as to each other. The first two plots illustrate the imaginariness. A combination of the last two explains the root number properties. $+\mathrm{i}$ and $-\mathrm{i}$ cases together yield the even number of roots. And we observe one peak, one shallow trench and one deeper trench.
The peak: $0<a<\pi/2$ roots
The shallow trench: $-\pi/2<a<0$ roots
The shallow trench and the deeper trench: $a<-\pi/2$ roots
Note that the transition from 2 roots to 4 roots consists in the evident stepwise behavior from the peak to the deeper trench.
[image: bird's eye-view]
[image: side view]

Please feel free to edit and elaborate!

Answer (score 1):

**This is not intend to be a canonical answer, but rather a guide of discusion**

Let $q=\sinh z$, we can get:
$$
\frac{1}{2}(\frac{a}{q+\frac{\pi}{2}i}+\frac{q+\frac{\pi}{2}i}{a}) + \tanh q=0
$$

Let's imagine $q$ is purely imaginary, let $q=i(t-\pi/2), t\in \mathcal{R}$, $z=\sinh q=i\sin(t-\pi/2)=-i\cos t$.

Then we get the following equation for $t$:

$$
\frac{1}{2}(\frac{t}{a}-\frac{a}{t})=\cot t
$$

Note in this equation, if $t_0$ is an solution, then $-t_0$ is also a solution, but this won't give us a distinct value of $z$.

Using mathematica, we plot out the left and right side of the above equation, we can see there are many intersections, for almost every real value of $a\neq0$.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Continuing from here:
$$
\frac{1}{2}(\frac{a}{q+\frac{\pi}{2}i}+\frac{q+\frac{\pi}{2}i}{a}) + \tanh q=0
$$
The [power series representation of arctanh](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcTanh.html) is
$$
arctanh(q)=x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}+\dots
$$
Using that approximation, we can solve with either the Cardano method to solve [quartic equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuarticEquation.html), or with numerical methods (e.g. [Newton-Raphson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method)):
$$
\frac{-1}{2}(\frac{a}{q+\frac{\pi}{2}i}+\frac{q+\frac{\pi}{2}i}{a}) = \tanh q
$$
$$
arctanh(\frac{-1}{2}(\frac{a}{q+\frac{\pi}{2}i}+\frac{q+\frac{\pi}{2}i}{a})) = q
$$

Comment: This is not exactly an answer. If one wants to apply numerical methods then the change from $z$ to $q$ is unnecessary, they could be applied to the original equation as well.